# I have an error in my school javascript project

Tags: javascript

I have multiple errors in my code. When I run the code, it gives an error saying that there is an unexpected identifier. Here is the full error, "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at /script.js:46:16". However, when I check through lines 46 through 16, I cant find any unclosed functions or methods. When I comment the if statement on line 46, it just gives an error on the other if statement. Can someone help me?

Heres the code:

```js
function print(str){
    console.log(str)
}

function farhToKelvin(far){
    const cel = Math.floor(far / (9/5) - 32)
    const kel = cel + 273
    return kel
}

function farhToCelsius(far){
    const cel = Math.floor(far / (9/5) - 32)
    return cel
}

function convertToFarh(type, val){
    type.toLowerCase()
    val.toLowerCase()
    if (type == "kelvin"){
        return Math.floor(far / (9/5) - 32 - 273)
    }
    else if(type == "celsius"){
        return Math.floor(far / (9/5) - 32)
    }
}


while (farh != "exit"){
    var farh = prompt("enter a farhanhite tempature: ")
    var type = prompt("convert it to celsius, or kelvin")
    type.toLowerCase()
    if (type == "celsius"){
        const c = farhToCelsius(farh)
        var val = convertToFarh(c)
        if (val > 50 or val == 50){
            print("it is cold, you should wear a coat")
        }
        if (val > 50 or val == 50){
            print("it is hot, you should wear a tank top")
        }
    }
    else if(type == "kelvin"){
        const k = farhToKelvin(farh)
        var val = convertToFarh(k)
        if (val > 50 or val == 50){
            print("it is cold, you should wear a coat")
        }
        if (val > 50 or val == 50){
            print("it is hot, you should wear a tank top")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe `script.js:46:16` means file script.js, line 46, column 16. So which line is 46?

Comment: `if (val > 50 or val == 50){` I don't think `or` is a valid alias for `||` (logical OR).

Comment: Also, `type.toLowerCase()` does not modify the original string so this line basically does nothing. Use `type = type.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (val > 50 or val == 50){
```

In Javascript, instead of `or`, we use `||`. If you have a similar problem again, you might want to take a look at [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if (val > 50 or val == 50)
```

to this

```
if (val > 50 || val == 50)
```

or better to this

```
if (val >= 50)
```

there are similar problems on line 50 and 60 and 64

you need to update them all.
logically line 46 and 50 are the same. based on you print message the line 50 should be
if (val > 50 ) but line 45 should be if ( val <= 50)

so you have both syntax and semantic problems in your code to address

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete list of the issues you have in your code:

- Using `or` instead of `||` (as others have stated)
- Using incorrect variable name in the `convertToFarh` function
- Omitting `type` parameter when calling `convertToFarh`
- Attempting to call `String.toLowerCase()` on a `number` variable
- Misspelling `fahrenheit`

### Using `or` instead of `||` ([Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR))

In your code, I believe you are intending to indicate `if (val > 50 || val == 50) {` instead of using `or` as used in other programming languages.

Before:

```js
        if (val > 50 or val == 50){
            print("it is cold, you should wear a coat")
        }
        if (val > 50 or val == 50){
            print("it is hot, you should wear a tank top")
        }
```

After:

```js
        if (val > 50 || val == 50){
            print("it is cold, you should wear a coat")
        }
        if (val > 50 || val == 50){
            print("it is hot, you should wear a tank top")
        }
```

This logic also doesn't make sense. Perhaps you mean `value < 50` in the first one and `val >= 50` in the second?

You also repeat yourself whether you're converting to/from Kelvin or Celsius, so that code could be extracted out into its own function or just reduce the `if..else` blocks down to only affect the necessary variables and perform the comparison after these blocks.

### Using incorrect variable name in `convertToFarh` function

In the `convertToFarh` function, you reference a variable named `far`, but there's no variable by that name. So you either mean to reference the `val` argument or you are trying to reference the `fahr` variable declared outside the function. In my code, I assume the former is the case `val` and rename it as follows:

```js
function convertToFarh(type, val){
    type.toLowerCase()
    val.toLowerCase()
    if (type == "kelvin"){
        return Math.floor(val / (9/5) - 32 - 273)
    }
    else if(type == "celsius"){
        return Math.floor(val / (9/5) - 32)
    }
}
```

### Omitting `type` parameter when calling `convertToFarh`

In both function calls to `convertToFarh`, you use the `c` or `k` variable as the value of the `val` parameter, but you don't indicate the type. I have fixed this to indicate the type for each part:

```js
var val = convertToFarh("celsius", c);
```

```js
var val = convertToFarh("kelvin", k);
```

### Attempting to call `String.toLowerCase()` on a `number` variable

In the `convertToFarh` function, you are attempting to call the `String.toLowerCase()` method on a `number` type (`val`) which gives an error. In my code, I simply commented this out and confirmed it can safely be removed.

### Misspelling `fahrenheit`

It might not seem like a big deal, but making sure variables have proper spelling helps when others are reviewing your code (whether bug-fixing or general code review). I have fixed function names, variable names, and any references to `fahrenheit` in your code to be the proper spelling. This includes:

- `"enter a fahrenheit temperature: "`
- `function fahrToKelvin` and function calls
- `function fahrToCelsius` and function calls
- `function convertToFahr` and function calls
- The variable named `farh` to `fahr`
- Function parameters named `far` were changed to `val` to avoid variable name collision

### Full code

```js
function print(str) {
  console.log(str);
}

function fahrToKelvin(val) {
  const cel = (val - 32) / (9 / 5);
  return Math.floor(cel + 273.15);
}

function fahrToCelsius(val) {
  const cel = Math.floor((val - 32) * 5 / 9);
  return cel;
}

function convertToFahr(type, val) {
  if (type == "kelvin") {
    return Math.floor(val / (5 / 9) - 459.67);
  } else if (type == "celsius") {
    return Math.floor(val / (9 / 5) + 32);
  }
}

var fahr = prompt("enter a fahrenheit tempature: ");
var type = prompt("convert it to celsius, or kelvin");
type = type.toLowerCase();
if (type == "celsius") {
  const c = fahrToCelsius(fahr);
  var val = convertToFahr("celsius", c);
  if (val < 50) {
    print("it is cold, you should wear a coat");
  }
  if (val >= 50) {
    print("it is hot, you should wear a tank top");
  }
} else if (type == "kelvin") {
  const k = fahrToKelvin(fahr);
  var val = convertToFahr("kelvin", k);
  if (val < 50) {
    print("it is cold, you should wear a coat");
  }
  if (val >= 50) {
    print("it is hot, you should wear a tank top");
  }
}
```